# Hidden sprout videos, embbeded in a iframe in a slick slider wont play

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, slick.js

I want my iframe to be draggable(left/right) inside a slick slider, to achieve this I have created an overlay div(iframe-overlay), and using the [SproutVideo Javascript Player API](https://sproutvideo.com/help/articles/27-javascript_player_api), I have bind an event, to play the sprout video when the overlay div is click.

In my slick slider I have set the "slidesToShow" to 3, all of these first 3 iframes will play the video when I click on it, my problem is when i slide to the fourth and nth slide, sproutvideo javascript player api, will not work anymore.

What is weird is, the bind event still gets called. How do i solved this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Below are my code.

HTML

```
<div class="parents-saying template-row row-margin-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="slider-grandparent-container element-margin-top">
            <div class="slider-parent-container">
                <div class="slider">
                    <?php foreach ($parents_saying['videos'] as $videos):?>
                        <slide>
                            <div class="iframe-container" style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:177.94253938832253%">
                                <iframe class="sproutvideo-player thirteenth-row-iframe" src="https://videos.sproutvideo.com/embed/<?=$videos['sprout_id'];?>"?playerTheme=dark&amp;playerColor=2f3437 style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border-radius:8px;" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade">
                                </iframe> 
                                <div class="iframe-overlay" id="<?=$videos['sprout_id'];?>"></div>
                            </div>
                        </slide>
                    <?php endforeach;?>
                </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
  $('.parents-saying .slider').slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    variableWidth: true,
    prevArrow:
      "<img class='a-left slider-arrow slick-prev' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-left-arrow.webp'>",
    nextArrow:
      "<img class='a-right slider-arrow slick-next' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-right-arrow.webp'>",
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
        }
      },
    ],
  });
  $('.parents-saying .iframe-overlay').bind('click', function(e){
    const sproutId = $(this).attr('id');  
    console.log('SPROUT ID: ', sproutId);
    const player   = new SV.Player({videoId: sproutId});
    player.play();
  });
```

Below is a screenshot of the slick slider
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@luna I think, the issue may be happened because the `iframe`s in the 4th and nth slide might not be initialized properly. This `SproutVideo player` needs to be initialized for each `iframe`.

To solve this issue, I use the Slick slider's `afterChange` event to detect when the slide changes and then initialize the `SproutVideo player` for the current slide.

This is code I tried:

```
$('.parents-saying .slider').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  variableWidth: true,
  prevArrow:
    "<img class='a-left slider-arrow slick-prev' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-left-arrow.webp'>",
  nextArrow:
    "<img class='a-right slider-arrow slick-next' src='/wp-content/uploads/2023/08/home-right-arrow.webp'>",
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
      }
    },
  ],
  // Add the following event handler to initialize SproutVideo player on slide change
  afterChange: function (slick, currentSlide) {
    const sproutId = $('.slick-current .iframe-overlay').attr('id');
    const player = new SV.Player({ videoId: sproutId });
    // Optionally, you may want to pause the player when changing slides
    // player.pause();
  }
});

$('.parents-saying .iframe-overlay').bind('click', function (e) {
  const sproutId = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log('SPROUT ID: ', sproutId);
  const player = new SV.Player({ videoId: sproutId });
  player.play();
});
```

Hope to be helpful for your understanding.

Comment: Hi I have tried this approach, video still wont play.

Answer (score 0):

@luna In my opinion, the issue maybe occurred when Slick Slider clones elements when the `variableWidth` set to `ture` or `slidesToShow` >= 1.

So, I tried to attach the click event to the `.slider-parent-container`.

Here is the modified JS code:

```
$('.parents-saying .slider').slick({
  // Your existing settings...
});

// Use event delegation to handle clicks on .iframe-overlay
$('.parents-saying .slider-parent-container').on('click', '.iframe-overlay', function(e) {
  const sproutId = $(this).attr('id');  
  console.log('SPROUT ID: ', sproutId);
  const player = new SV.Player({ videoId: sproutId });
  player.play();
});
```